# template class inheritance rules

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```
template<typename T>
struct cell
{
    cell(T row,T column)
    {
        cellid = std::make_pair<T, T>(row, column);
    }

    std::pair<T, T> getcellid();
private:
    std::pair<T, T> cellid;
};
```

Now, I have a matrix class that derives from `cell<T>`.

This works:

```
template<typename T>
class matrix : public cell<T>
{
};
```

This does not work:

```
class matrix : public cell<T>
// Error: T does not name a type
```

which is understandable.

The disadvantage with approach 1 is that, `matrix` class can now make use of template parameter `T`, which is not intended to happen in this use case.

Is there a way through which I can prevent `matrix` class from gaining access to template parameter while still being able to derive from class `cell`.

Comment: This makes no sense, how the compiler could know what T is ? Do you want `class matrix:public cell<double>` ? or `class matrix:public cell<int>` ? ...

Comment: Why don't you want `matrix` to access `T`?

Comment: matrix could be made of cells that consist of float/int values...Idea is to let cell handle that information.

Comment: @basav Then `matrix` has to be a template. Otherwise you won't know what type you want the cells to be.

Comment: Makes sense.I will proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to choose an actual type when instantiating the template class `cell<T>` as the base class of `matrix`. If `matrix` is not a template, then there's no type flexibility provided to any instantiation of `matrix`, and so the type `T` of `cell<T>` must be fully known in the definition of `matrix`. For example, this will work:

```
class matrix : public cell<int> { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how templates work.

It would be essentially impossible to write a useful `matrix` class that could not mention the type `T` of its cells. You couldn't return cell values or perform calculations on the cells.

The "working" class definition you wrote is what you need to use. The "not working" definition is not sensical to either a compiler or to me.

However, creating a matrix as a subclass of a single cell is probably not the design you actually intend anyway. A matrix is an array of multiple cells, not a specialized type of cell. You probably want something like this.

```
class matrix
{
     cell<float>  c[3][3];
};
```

But it's hard to say because you aren't clear about it, and your cells embed a row and column value (mysteriously to me) so without more code, I can't be certain. Your design is definitely weird though.

Comment: you could have  a matrix that has cells that consist of float values/int values....hence, I was trying out templates..I am learning the use of templates